# How can I plot histogram with the same number of values in every bin?

Tags: plotting, histograms

For example I have 100 values sample. I'd like to build histogram in which every bin contains, for example, 10 values. How can i do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the values of the [**quantiles**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) of your sample as bin delimiters for your histogram. You can think of $n$-quantiles as those threshold values that divide your data set into $n$ equal-sized subsets.

Let's generate some sample data and set your requirements, i.e. number of points per bin:

```
SeedRandom[10]
sample = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200];
datapointsperbin = 10;
numberofbins = IntegerPart[Length[sample]/datapointsperbin];
```

This is what a regular histogram with evenly spaced bins would look like for that sample:

```
Histogram[sample]
```

[image: Even binned histogram]

Now we use `Quantile` to calculate `numberofbins` quantiles for your distribution, then we use those values as bin delimiters for your histogram.

```
Histogram[
 sample,
 {Table[Quantile[sample, i/numberofbins], {i, 1, numberofbins - 1}]}
]
```

[image: unevenly binned histogram]

You can see from the vertical axis of the histogram that each bin contains 10 samples, as specified by the value of `datapointperbin`.

---

Having done this, however, I still wonder why you need such a histogram. Of course, if what you needed was to calculate the intervals that would accomplish such binning, given your sample, the magic is all in the `Quantile` function, so you can get those values directly as well:

```
Table[Quantile[sample, i/numberofbins], {i, 1, numberofbins - 1}]
```

> {-1.8614, -1.42414, -1.21859, -0.971859, -0.905122, -0.707023, -0.470983, -0.274088, -0.163548, 0.0100698, 0.122639, 0.271601, 0.383704, 0.475579, 0.608299, 0.873699, 1.03975, 1.33463, 1.81741}

Comment: Wow, thanks for help. One more question: how to change y-axis value from 'number of values in each bin' to 'probability density function value for each bin'?

Comment: `Histogram` can do that for you: just add "PDF" as the bin height specification, as the following: `Histogram[ sample, Table[Quantile[sample, i/numberofbins], {i, 1, numberofbins - 1}]}, "PDF" ]`.

Answer (score 6):

You can also define a function that produces the required bin list:

```
ClearAll[bF]
bF[n_] := {Quantile[#, Range[# - 1]/# &[Quotient[Length@#, n]]]} &
```

where we used the fact that the second argument of `Quantile` can be a `List`.

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200];
Row[Histogram[data, bF[10][data], #, PlotLabel -> Style[#, 16, "Panel"],
    ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ImageSize -> 400, ChartStyle -> 63] & /@
  {"PDF", "Count"}]
```

[image]

**Update:** With multiple datasets, we can specify the bin lengths in a number of ways.

Using the one of the data sets as the source for specifying the bin lengths, we get an interesting *comparative* histogram of the two data sets:

```
datab = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {2, 200}];

Row[Histogram[datab, bF[10][First@datab], #, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[#, 16, "Panel"],
    ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ImageSize -> 400, 
    ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
    ChartLegends -> Placed[{"data1", "data2"}, Bottom]] & /@
  {"PDF", "Count"}]
```

[image]

```
Row[Histogram[datab, bF[10][Last@datab], #, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[#, 16, "Panel"],
    ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ImageSize -> 400, 
    ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
    ChartLegends -> Placed[{"data1", "data2"}, Bottom]] & /@
  {"PDF", "Count"}]
```

[image]

Specifying bin lengths based on  `Join`ed data sets, and on the `Union` of data sets, we get the following:

```
Row[Histogram[datab, bF[20][Join @@ datab], #, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[#, 16, "Panel"],
    ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ImageSize -> 400, 
    ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
    ChartLegends -> Placed[{"data1", "data2"}, Bottom]] & /@
  {"PDF", "Count"}]
```

[image]

```
Row[Histogram[datab, bF[10][First@Union@datab], #, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[#, 16, "Panel"],
    ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ImageSize -> 400, 
    ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
    ChartLegends -> Placed[{"data1", "data2"}, Bottom]] & /@
  {"PDF", "Count"}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's absolutely amazing. Thank You a lot.

Comment: @instajke, my pleasure.

Comment: Very nice and great idea.

Comment: Thank you @Algohi.