# How to plot frequency polygon?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, histograms, charts

I have data sample. Built and plotted histogram based on the sample. How can I plot frequency polygon now?

[image]

That's example of the desired result.

Here is code:

```
 n = 100;
 a = 0;
 b = π;

 datapointsperbin = 10;
 numberofbins = IntegerPart[Length[data]/datapointsperbin];

 data = Sort[
 Sin[(b - a)*RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], n] + a]];

 (*even bins*)
 Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", LabelingFunction -> Above, ChartStyle -> Pink]

 (*uneven bins*)
 Histogram[data, {Table[Quantile[data, i/numberofbins], {i, 1, numberofbins}]}, "PDF"]
```

I'd like to understand how i could plot polygon for both cases: with even and uneven bins.
Thank You.

Comment: Provide your sample data and your code for the `Histogram`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** An alternative approach is to extract coordinates of the `Rectangle`s and use `Show` similar to the approach @Algohi's answer.

We define an auxiliary function `lF` to generate the coordinates for the line we need, and use it in the function `showF` that takes an `Histogram` as input and `Show`s it together with a line joining the midpoints of the rectangle tops:

```
ClearAll[lF, showF]
lF = Cases[#, RectangleBox[a_, b_, ___] :> ({Mean[#1], Last@#2} & @@ Transpose[{a, b}]), 
    {0, Infinity}] &;
showF[dirs_: {Thick, Red}] := Show[#, Epilog -> {## & @@ dirs, Line@lF@#}] &;

hist = Histogram[data, bF[10][data], "PDF", LabelingFunction -> Above, 
 ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ChartStyle -> Pink];
showF[] @ hist
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
showF[{Thick, Blue}] @ hist
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This approach avoids the glitch mentioned by the OP in the comments below. It seems that there is glitch/bug with the `Joined` option of `RectangleChart`. The method proposed in the original post gives

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = Sort[Sin[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{a, b}], n]]]; 

rc = With[{hl = HistogramList[data, bF[10][data], "PDF"]}, 
 RectangleChart[Transpose[{Differences@First@hl, Last@hl}], 
  Joined -> Automatic, BarSpacing -> 0, 
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[N@Last@#, Above] &), ChartStyle -> Pink,
   Frame -> {Bottom, Left}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The last point in the `Line` produced by the `Joined` option is wrong:

```
Cases[rc, _Line, {0, Infinity}][[1]]
```

> Line[{{0.124947, 0.500214}, {0.321742, 0.869881}, {0.422127,   2.19024},
>          {0.512293, 1.01411}, {0.609398, 1.76182}, {0.68612,  1.51524}, {0.760101, 1.9094},
>          **{0.787629, 4.17077}**}]

---

**Original post:**

You can also use `HistogramList` as input to `BarChart` which has the option `Joined`:

```
BarChart[N@Last@HistogramList[data, Automatic, "PDF"], 
 Joined -> Automatic, LabelingFunction -> Above, ChartStyle -> Pink]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also add ticks to get a look closer to the output of `Histogram`:

```
With[{hl = HistogramList[data, Automatic, "PDF"]}, 
 BarChart[N@Last@hl, Joined -> Automatic,
  BarSpacing -> 0, LabelingFunction -> Above, ChartStyle -> Pink, 
  Frame -> {Bottom, Left}, AxesOrigin -> {1/2, 0}, 
  FrameTicks -> {Thread[{Range@Length@First@hl - 1/2, First@hl}] &, Automatic}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** Perhaps, `RectangleChart`, which also has the option `Joined`, is more flexible in that (1) `Ticks` are automatically picked from input data, and (2) you can have unequal bin widths.

```
With[{hl = HistogramList[data, Automatic, "PDF"]},
 RectangleChart[Transpose[{Differences@First@hl, Last@hl}], 
  Joined -> Automatic,
  BarSpacing -> 0, LabelingFunction -> (Placed[N@Last@#, Above] &), 
  ChartStyle -> Pink,
  Frame -> {Bottom, Left}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
bF[n_] := {Quantile[#, Range[# - 1]/# &[Quotient[Length@#, n]]]} &
```

To have each bin to contain 10 data points, use the bin specs `bF[10][data]`:

```
With[{hl = HistogramList[data, bF[10][data], "PDF"]},
 RectangleChart[Transpose[{Differences@First@hl, Last@hl}], 
  Joined -> Automatic,
  BarSpacing -> 0, LabelingFunction -> (Placed[N@Last@#, Above] &), 
  ChartStyle -> Pink,
  Frame -> {Bottom, Left}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Well, again absolutely beautiful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: excuse me, faced the problem: http://i.imgur.com/ZnTbWUk.png
How to fix this? As i understand, i can't just set Y-axis range.

Comment: @instajke, could you post the code that produced the picture in the link? And  the Mathematica version you are using?

Comment: i just used my data, u can find it in the question. Mathematica version is 10.0.1.0
Thanks.

Comment: @instajke, could you add the value of `numberofbins` in your question?

Comment: oh, sorry, added.
Here is the full code and this plot: http://i.imgur.com/GuIPmVe.png

Comment: @instajke, I was able to reproduce the issue in both  version 9.0.1.0 and version 10 - it seems that there is glitch/bug  with the `Joined` option of `RectangleChart`. I update with an alternative method similar to @Algohi's.

Answer (score 6):

Your histogram doesn't have regular binning, so you will want to specify how you want the binning done in your question. To get you started, however, here is an idea with regular binning. Otherwise you could adapt the code from your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83614/27951) on uneven binning to this problem.

```
SeedRandom[10]
sample = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200];

histogramdata = HistogramList[sample, Automatic, "PDF"];
frequencypolygondata = Transpose[{
    Mean /@ Partition[histogramdata[[1]], 2, 1],
    histogramdata[[2]]
    }];

Show[
 Histogram[sample, Automatic, "PDF"],
 ListPlot[frequencypolygondata, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Thick]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Update:**

For the sake of completeness, if you want to use the conditions from your previous question (i.e. ten data points per bin), of course you can use the same approach that I outlined there:

```
SeedRandom[10]
sample = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200];
datapointsperbin = 10;
numberofbins = IntegerPart[Length[sample]/datapointsperbin];

histogramdata = HistogramList[
   sample,
   {Table[Quantile[sample, i/numberofbins], {i, 1, numberofbins - 1}]},
   "PDF"];
frequencypolygondata = Transpose[{
    Mean /@ Partition[histogramdata[[1]], 2, 1],
    histogramdata[[2]]
    }];

Show[
 Histogram[sample,
  {Table[Quantile[sample, i/numberofbins], {i, 1, numberofbins - 1}]},
  "PDF"],
 ListPlot[frequencypolygondata, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Thick]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow, wow! Thanks a lot again :)

Comment: @instajke No problem, glad to be of help! I am guessing that you may want to combine the results from the previous question about uneven binning with this one, to produce a plot like the one in the example. If that's the case, you could amend the question to be more specific, and I'll see what I can do to match the answer.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i need, to combine polygon and the histogram from previous question.

Comment: @instajke I updated my answer to include uneven binning as well

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way:

```
histogram := Histogram[
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200],
  Automatic,
  Function[{bins, counts}, Sow[bins, "bins"]; Sow[counts, "counts"]]
  ]

{g, bins} = Reap[histogram];

Show[
 g,
 Graphics@Line@MapThread[{Mean[#], #2} &, Flatten[bins, 1]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

```
sample = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200];
histogramdata = 
     Histogram[sample, {Sort@RandomReal[{-4, 4}, 20]}, "PDF"];
h = Cases[histogramdata, StatusArea[_, x_] :> x, -1];
w = Cases[histogramdata, 
   RectangleBox[{x_, _}, {y_, _} | NCache[{y_, _}, _], __] :> 
    Mean@{x, y}, -1];
Show[histogramdata, ListLinePlot[Transpose[{w, h}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thank You!