Styling histograms
Consider this code:
With[{d = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 3], 10^4]}, 
 Show[Histogram[d, {Min[d], Max[d], (Max[d] - Min[d])/30}, 
   "ProbabilityDensity", ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Log"}, 
   Frame -> True, ChartStyle -> {Opacity[.25, Red]}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 22], ImageSize -> Large, 
   FrameLabel -> {quantity, "Fraction"}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"XXX"}], 18, Black](*,
   ChartLegends\[Rule]Placed[{"With weights","Pure phase space"},
   Bottom]*)]]]

It produces a filled histogram:

How is it possible to make an unfilled histogram (so only its boundary is visible)? It should be like ListPlot[data,Joined->True,InterpolationOrder->0].
Edit
An alternative option would be to use BinCounts followed by the ordinary ListPlot. It looks like it would work simpler.

Possible duplicate:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83618/how-to-plot-frequency-polygon.

You can also use HistogramList + ListStepPlot:
SeedRandom[1];
With[{d = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 3], 10^4]}, 
 hl = HistogramList[d, {Min[d], Max[d], (Max[d] - Min[d])/30}, 
   "ProbabilityDensity"]; 
 ListStepPlot[hl[[2]], ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Log"}, 
  DataRange -> MinMax[hl[[1]]], Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.25, Red], Filling -> Axis, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 22], ImageSize -> Large, 
  FrameLabel -> {quantity, "Fraction"}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"XXX"}], 18, Black]]]



+1 This seems better than my method because you don't have to re-evaluate the PDF at the bin values.

One possibility is to stop using histograms altogether (and especially stop scaling the vertical axis on a log scale) and use nonparametric density estimates.  This has been readily available since the late 20-th century.
With[{d = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 3], 10^4]},
 Show[SmoothHistogram[d, Automatic, "PDF", Frame -> True,
   PlotRange -> {All, {0, All}},
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 22], ImageSize -> Large,
   FrameLabel -> {"Quantity", "Probability density"},
   PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"XXX"}], 18, Black]]]]


And about the log-scaling of the vertical axis:  Yes, you can do it.  But the area under the curve is no longer 1 and is an arbitrary value depending on what is used as the smallest vertical value.  The shape becomes uninterpretable especially if one is comparing other distributions.

You can do exactly what you're hinting at with HistogramDistribution. I use your given binning specification:
SeedRandom[123];
d = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 3], 10^4];
dStep = (Max[d] - Min[d])/30;


dist = HistogramDistribution[d, {Min[d], Max[d], dStep}];
bins = Range[Min[d], Max[d], dStep];
pdfVals = {#, PDF[dist, #]} & /@ bins;

ListLinePlot[pdfVals, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Log"}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.25, Red]}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 22],
  ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {"quantity", "Fraction"}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"XXX"}], 18, Black]]



Also just worth noting: I use the automatic binning spec for HistogramDistribution, but HistogramDistribution also allows a custom binning specification (much like Histogram) if you so desire.

You can also use DiscretePlot on the PDF itself without making the table, but I don't know how to control the InterpolationOrder of DiscretePlot (it seems to always be InterpolationOrder -> 1 when Joined -> True):

DiscretePlot[PDF[dist, x], {x, Min[d], Max[d], (Max[d] - Min[d])/30}, 
 Joined -> True, Filling -> None, (*...same plot options as before...*)]




A third option is to use Plot on PDF and set Exclusions -> None. This probably adds a lot of extra computations of the PDF at unnecessary points though:
Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, Min[d], Max[d]}, Exclusions -> None, 
(*...same plot options as before... *)]



